# Python RPC Time module function not found

Tags: python, grpc-python

I am trying to get started with Python + gRCP and so I checked out their repository as mentioned in the gRPC guide (https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python/).

Now I could execute the `Hello World`-Script (Client + Server), and so I tried to modify it. To ensure I did not missconfigure anything I just extended the `Hello World`-function (that use to work out before). I added the following lines:

```
import time

def SayHello(self, request, context):
        currentTime = time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_REALTIME)
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Time is, %s!' % currentTime)
```

Now what I inmagined it would do is to simply pass the `currentTime`-object back in this message I am returning upon that function is called - yet, what happens is the following error:

> ERROR:grpc._server:Exception calling application: 'module' object has
>   no attribute 'clock_gettime' Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_server.py", line
>   435, in _call_behavior
>       response_or_iterator = behavior(argument, context)   File "greeter_server.py", line 29, in SayHello
>       currentTime = time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_REALTIME) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'clock_gettime'

I tried to Google around and I found that this might occur if you have a file named `time` in the same directory (so Python confuses the file in the current directory with the time-file. Yet there is no such file and he seems to find the correct `time`-file (since I can see the documentation when I hover the import and the function). What did I do wrong here?

The "full" Server Code (up to the `serve()` function):

```
from concurrent import futures
import logging
import time

import grpc

import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        currentTime = time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_REALTIME)
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Time is, %s!' % currentTime)
```

Edit: I am using Ubuntu if that is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.clock_gettime` is a 3.3+ API and you are using 2.7.